# How to append recursive API calls and write results to CSV?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, csv, elementtree

I have to create csv out of an XML API response. I am having two issues. One - for some reason, the API calls I am making are not saving to a list after appending, the list disappears completely.

two - since I can not store the results from the API call, I dont know how to crawl over the results and create a csv.

The code is setup to first get group level data, then take each ID and apply to people.profile API call to get their profile information. I can do this part, here is the code:

```
def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>2.25</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>001</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Sa.People.Profile.Get">
           <ID>{}</ID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)      


xml ='''    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<YourMembership>
    <Version>2.25</Version>
    <ApiKey>xxxx</ApiKey>
    <CallID>001</CallID>
    <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
    <Call Method="Sa.Groups.Group.GetMembershipLog">
        <GroupID>12345</GroupID>
        <ItemID></ItemID>
        <StartDate></StartDate>
    </Call>
</YourMembership>
'''        
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', data=xml, headers=headers)
print r.text
# BUILD XML TREE OBJECT    
tree = et.fromstring(r.text)

storage = []
# PARSE People ID TEXT AND PASS INTO FUNCTION
for i in tree.iterfind('.//ID'):
     y = xml_event_info(i.text)
     storage.append(y)
```

At the comment 'parse people ID text and pass into function, as I am iterating over the API call, the values are not being saved into list 'storage' and for reason, once the call has ended 'storage' disappears, and when i go to print the list 'storage' it says 'None'.

Secondly, the `y = xml_event_info(i.text)` is the actual people profile data I need to parse into CSV and this is how the XML looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<YourMembership_Response>
<ErrCode>0</ErrCode>
<ExtendedErrorInfo></ExtendedErrorInfo>
<Sa.People.Profile.Get>
<ID>098765</ID>
<WebsiteID>1234</WebsiteID>
<PrimaryGroupCode>abc</PrimaryGroupCode>
<IsMember>1</IsMember>
<IsNonMember>0</IsNonMember>
<Registered>2017-09-07 18:48:00</Registered>
<LastUpdated>2017-09-11 15:19:54</LastUpdated>
<ImportID>u293248</ImportID>
<ConstituentID></ConstituentID>
<EmailAddr>xxxx</EmailAddr>
<EmailBounced>0</EmailBounced>
<NamePrefix>xxx</NamePrefix>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<MiddleName></MiddleName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
<NameSuffix></NameSuffix>
<Nickname></Nickname>
<Gender>M</Gender>
<Birthdate></Birthdate>
<MaritalStatus></MaritalStatus>
<MaidenName></MaidenName>
<SpouseName></SpouseName>
<AnniversaryDate></AnniversaryDate>
<Employer>Welk Resorts</Employer>
<Title>xxxx</Title>
<Profession></Profession>
<Membership>xxxxx</Membership>
<MembershipExpiry>2017-09-08 00:00:00</MembershipExpiry>
<MemberTypeCode>xxxx</MemberTypeCode>
<Approved>1</Approved>
<Suspended>1</Suspended>
<Username>xx@xx.com</Username>
<PasswordHash>xxxx</PasswordHash>
<AltEmailAddr>xxxx</AltEmailAddr>
<HomeAddrLines></HomeAddrLines>
<HomeCity></HomeCity>
<HomeLocation>xxxx</HomeLocation>
<HomePostalCode></HomePostalCode>
<HomeCountry>United States</HomeCountry>
<Website></Website>
<HomePhAreaCode></HomePhAreaCode>
<HomePhone></HomePhone>
<MobileAreaCode></MobileAreaCode>
<Mobile></Mobile>
<EmpAddrLines></EmpAddrLines>
<EmpCity></EmpCity>
<EmpLocation>Alabama</EmpLocation>
<EmpPostalCode></EmpPostalCode>
<EmpCountry>United States</EmpCountry>
<BusinessWebsite></BusinessWebsite>
<EmpPhAreaCode></EmpPhAreaCode>
<EmpPhone></EmpPhone>
<EmpFaxAreaCode></EmpFaxAreaCode>
<EmpFax></EmpFax>
<HeadshotImageURI></HeadshotImageURI>
<LastRenewalReminderSent></LastRenewalReminderSent>
<GamificationPoints></GamificationPoints>
<MasterID></MasterID>
<LastRenewalDate>2017-09-07 00:00:00</LastRenewalDate>
<ApprovalDate>9/11/2017 00:00:00 PM</ApprovalDate>
<LastModifiedDate>2017-09-11 00:00:00 </LastModifiedDate>
<QueuedForDelete>0</QueuedForDelete>
<QueuedForDeleteDate></QueuedForDeleteDate>
<Latitude>0</Latitude>
<Longitude>0</Longitude>
<MembershipExpires>1</MembershipExpires>
<MembershipEffectiveExpiresDate>2017-09-08 00:00:00</MembershipEffectiveExpiresDate>
<CustomFieldResponses>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>Member Referral</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>Individual</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="ReferredBy" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>xxxx</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>Practitioner</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>xxxxx</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="ApprovalDate" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>9.8.17</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="ChapterApproval" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>declined 9.11.17</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="whois" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="HelpingHandsSummary" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="APCProspect" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="formerchapter" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>San Diego</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
</CustomFieldResponses>
</Sa.People.Profile.Get>
</YourMembership_Response>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<YourMembership_Response>
<ErrCode>0</ErrCode>
<ExtendedErrorInfo></ExtendedErrorInfo>
<Sa.People.Profile.Get>
<ID>098765</ID>
<WebsiteID>1234</WebsiteID>
<PrimaryGroupCode>abc</PrimaryGroupCode>
<IsMember>1</IsMember>
<IsNonMember>0</IsNonMember>
<Registered>2017-09-07 18:48:00</Registered>
<LastUpdated>2017-09-11 15:19:54</LastUpdated>
<ImportID>u293248</ImportID>
<ConstituentID></ConstituentID>
<EmailAddr>xxxx</EmailAddr>
<EmailBounced>0</EmailBounced>
<NamePrefix>xxx</NamePrefix>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<MiddleName></MiddleName>
<LastName>Smith</LastName>
<NameSuffix></NameSuffix>
<Nickname></Nickname>
<Gender>M</Gender>
<Birthdate></Birthdate>
<MaritalStatus></MaritalStatus>
<MaidenName></MaidenName>
<SpouseName></SpouseName>
<AnniversaryDate></AnniversaryDate>
<Employer>Welk Resorts</Employer>
<Title>xxxx</Title>
<Profession></Profession>
<Membership>xxxxx</Membership>
<MembershipExpiry>2017-09-08 00:00:00</MembershipExpiry>
<MemberTypeCode>xxxx</MemberTypeCode>
<Approved>1</Approved>
<Suspended>1</Suspended>
<Username>xx@xx.com</Username>
<PasswordHash>xxxx</PasswordHash>
<AltEmailAddr>xxxx</AltEmailAddr>
<HomeAddrLines></HomeAddrLines>
<HomeCity></HomeCity>
<HomeLocation>xxxx</HomeLocation>
<HomePostalCode></HomePostalCode>
<HomeCountry>United States</HomeCountry>
<Website></Website>
<HomePhAreaCode></HomePhAreaCode>
<HomePhone></HomePhone>
<MobileAreaCode></MobileAreaCode>
<Mobile></Mobile>
<EmpAddrLines></EmpAddrLines>
<EmpCity></EmpCity>
<EmpLocation>Alabama</EmpLocation>
<EmpPostalCode></EmpPostalCode>
<EmpCountry>United States</EmpCountry>
<BusinessWebsite></BusinessWebsite>
<EmpPhAreaCode></EmpPhAreaCode>
<EmpPhone></EmpPhone>
<EmpFaxAreaCode></EmpFaxAreaCode>
<EmpFax></EmpFax>
<HeadshotImageURI></HeadshotImageURI>
<LastRenewalReminderSent></LastRenewalReminderSent>
<GamificationPoints></GamificationPoints>
<MasterID></MasterID>
<LastRenewalDate>2017-09-07 00:00:00</LastRenewalDate>
<ApprovalDate>9/11/2017 00:00:00 PM</ApprovalDate>
<LastModifiedDate>2017-09-11 00:00:00 </LastModifiedDate>
<QueuedForDelete>0</QueuedForDelete>
<QueuedForDeleteDate></QueuedForDeleteDate>
<Latitude>0</Latitude>
<Longitude>0</Longitude>
<MembershipExpires>1</MembershipExpires>
<MembershipEffectiveExpiresDate>2017-09-08 00:00:00</MembershipEffectiveExpiresDate>
<CustomFieldResponses>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>Member Referral</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>Individual</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="ReferredBy" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>xxxx</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>Practitioner</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>xxxxx</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="xxxx" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="ApprovalDate" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>9.8.17</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="ChapterApproval" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>declined 9.11.17</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="whois" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="HelpingHandsSummary" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="APCProspect" Visibility="">
<Values></Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
<CustomFieldResponse FieldCode="formerchapter" Visibility="">
<Values>
<Value>San Diego</Value>
</Values>
</CustomFieldResponse>
</CustomFieldResponses>
</Sa.People.Profile.Get>
</YourMembership_Response>
```

Is there anyway I can quickly make each xml tag a column in a csv? I dont mind manually typing out the fields to write in either if I have too. But would like to save and split results into csv. The CSV should look like this:

```
ID     FirstName   LastName EmailAddr
12312   John        Smith    john@smith.com
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Rusty, notice that the function `xml_event_info` doesn't return its result.

Comment: That solved #1 - thanks Bill!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gets the tags and texts for the 'children' in each profile in the input xml file. But *be careful*, this code does not attempt to compile a complete set of all of the tags that appear in all of the profiles. If some profiles have tags that others do not then this will make for complications in writing a csv file because you need to know how many columns there are in the csv before you start writing it.

```
def xml_event_info(eventID):       
    xml ='''        
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <YourMembership>
       <Version>2.25</Version>
       <ApiKey>xxxx</ApiKey>
       <CallID>001</CallID>
       <></>
       <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
       <Call Method = "Sa.People.Profile.Get">
           <ID>{}</ID>
       </Call>
    </YourMembership>        
    '''        
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', 
                      data=xml.format(eventID), headers=headers)        
    print(r.text)      


xml ='''    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<YourMembership>
    <Version>2.25</Version>
    <ApiKey>xxxx</ApiKey>
    <CallID>001</CallID>
    <SaPasscode>xxxx</SaPasscode>
    <Call Method="Sa.Groups.Group.GetMembershipLog">
        <GroupID>12345</GroupID>
        <ItemID></ItemID>
        <StartDate></StartDate>
    </Call>
</YourMembership>
'''        
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
r = requests.post('https://api.yourmembership.com', data=xml, headers=headers)

from xml.etree import et
tree = et.fromstring(r.text)
people_profiles = tree.findall('.//Sa.People.Profile.Get')
for people_profile in people_profiles:
    'New profile'
    for c, child in enumerate(people_profile.getchildren()):
        print (child.tag, child.text)
```

Comment: When I run this, I replaced 'temp.xml' with 'r.text' or 'y', I get the error 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getchildren''. Is this because 'first_item' is not iterable?

Comment: I think the XML has no child tags so the getchildren will not work.

Comment: I should have mentioned, you will need to modify the code to get all of the `Sa.People.Profile.Get` items using `findall` then, in a loop, for each of these use a loop like the one in my code to get all of the children. I did it in this way only because the file had just one person in it.

Comment: When you say get children, how can I do that if the xml has no children? they all seem to be xpaths. Also your line `first_item = tree.find('.//Sa.People.Profile.Get')` is becoming a list so I am not even getting the option to enumerate over the tree. 

I also changed 'first_item = tree.find('.//Sa.People.Profile.Get')' too 'first_item = tree.findall('.//Sa.People.Profile.Get')' is this what you had in mind? 

Thank you once again for all the help

Comment: Rusty, I've replaced the earlier code. I hope this is clearer.

Comment: Bill, the error message from your loop is gone, but nothing is printing. I think because I am using the variable 'y' in my case since that is where the profile information is being stored. Instead of your line 'tree = ElementTree.parse('temp.xml')' i am doing 'tree = ElementTree.parse(y)'. Do you think that is not correct?

Comment: Just to add to your comment, every profile will have the same columns as it is coming from the same group.

Comment: Also the code is not going over every profile, just the first one. I am attempting to find way to go over all the profiles

Comment: The code in my answer now includes part of the code from your question to show how to put the two together. Hope this helps. You will still need to write the part to put the data into the csv file. This can be done in a way that is similar to what I showed in a previous answer.

Comment: Bill still not able to loop through all the calls, I can work on that from here. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Welcome. Wish I could help more but can't without seeing actual result from that site. Best of luck.